# how to set label like Sale and new on product media in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have custom design create in magneto front-end and i have set product label for 
product image place .

**I have no idea how to set label on product image so help and understand this code .**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use Solwin Infotech Advanced Product Labels Magento 2 extension.

Magento 2 Advanced Product Labels extension allows store owners to display different product labels like Hot (Best Seller), Sale, Offer, Featured, New etc…on product view and category view page to motivate customer’s purchasing behavior.

Refer below link for more details:
https://www.solwininfotech.com/product/magento-2-extensions/advanced-product-labels-magento-2/